# An integral of modified bessel functions

Tags: integration, mathematical-physics, bessel-functions

How to integrate the expression ${(\frac{\omega \rho}{3c})}^2(\frac{1}{\gamma^2}+\theta^2)^2[K^2_{2/3}(\xi) +\frac{\theta^2}{\frac{1}{\gamma^2}+\theta^2}K^2_{1/3}(\xi)]$  w.r.t.  $d\theta$ for the limit -infinity  to infinity, where $\xi = (\omega \rho)/(3c)[1/\gamma^2 + \theta^2]^{3/2}$.
This is the expression to obtain the formula for power distribution of synchrotron radiation  per solid angle from a uniform circular motion of the electron.

The final answer is an integral of linear $K_{5/3}(\xi)d\xi$ from $\xi_{(\theta=0)}$ to infinity multiplied by $\xi_{(\theta=0)}$.

(Ref: J.D. Jackson, chapter 14)

Comment: One method of how it is solved is provided in [Jackson solutions](http://www.scribd.com/doc/31752818/Classical-Electrodynamics-3rd-Ed-J-D-Jackson-Solutions-214-Pg#scribd)

Comment: Really? Didn't refer to those, since this is not actually a problem. The result of the integral is provided in the text without any derivation.

Comment: Problem 14.8 has a similar integral to evaluate. The reference is to Watson's book on Bessel functions. The integral is one that has confused many and can, by the properties of Bessel functions and use of Watson's book be evaluated.